# How do I get LIKE not to match accented characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode

I'm trying to write a query on [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) that looks for certain accented characters in the titles of posts - something like this:

```sql
SELECT
  b.Id AS [Post Link]
FROM
  Posts b
WHERE
  b.Title LIKE '%[ĀāĒēĪīŌōŪūÂâÊêÎîÔôÛû]%'
```

This, unfortunately, returns any post whose title contains a vowel at all, accented or not, as we can see by running:

```sql
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN 'tuv' LIKE '%[ĀāĒēĪīŌōŪūÂâÊêÎîÔôÛû]%'
    THEN 'matched'
    ELSE 'not matched'
  END
```

which results in `'matched'` being returned.

What should I do to perform a query that selects only those rows for which `Title` contains one of the accented characters I've specified? From my vague understanding of SQL, I've been led to believe that this might entail using `COLLATE` somehow. (Note that I don't have control over the database in this case, so I can't change any settings at the table or database level or anything - I have to work with what SEDE already supplies.)

Comment: You need to use `N` prefix when working with unicode string do something like    `WHERE LIKE N'%[ĀāĒēĪīŌōŪūÂâÊêÎîÔôÛû]%'`

Comment: @M.Ali Oh wow, that was simple! Would you like to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you are missing is the `N` prefix. When working with unicode characters you always need to tell sql server explicitly that strings can contain some unicode character by prefixing the string with `N`

```
SELECT
  b.Id AS [Post Link]
FROM
  Posts b
WHERE
  b.Title LIKE N'%[ĀāĒēĪīŌōŪūÂâÊêÎîÔôÛû]%'
```

Same is true when you are inserting, Updating data

```
INSERT INTO TableName(ColumName)
VALUES (N'ĀāĒēĪīŌōŪūÂâÊêÎîÔô')
```